# Under which circumstances does iOS call -accessibilityScroll:?

Tags: ios, uitableview, accessibility, uipickerview, voiceover

I implemented all accessibility action methods in my table view and added the "adjustable" trait. I made custom control with UITableView to select an item by scrolling. It does not have typical rows to select. It is intended for scrolling and a marker shows what is selected. Similar to UIPickerView or the selector in Weightbot. It is a custom [date picker control](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/mwdatepicker) to select event date.

But iOS never calls my accessibility action methods. A flick up or down in the table view Voice Over does not react properly. It wildly jumps around.

Must I set a delegate or data source for voice over? How can I get it to correctly scoll my table view up / down when user flicks up / down like in UIPickerView?

It would help a lot to understand how exactly Apple made UIDatePicker accessible with VoiceOver. It uses UITableView for each column. You can drag between columns to select column. Then you can flick up down to increase or decrease.

**EDIT**: Dumped recursively info about UIDatePicker to see how it is set up.

```
 UIDatePicker: 
     _UIDatePickerView: 
         UIView: 
         _UIOnePartImageView: 
         _UIPickerWheelView: 
         _UIPickerViewSelectionBar: 
         UIPickerTableView:; contentOffset: {0, 2.19991e+06}>
             UIPickerTableViewWrapperCell: 
                 UITableViewCellContentView: 
                 UIDatePickerWeekMonthDayView: 
                     UILabel: {label = 28. Jul} {traits = staticText } {accessibilityIncrement} {accessibilityDecrement} {accessibilityScroll:} {accessibilityPerformEscape} {accessibilityPerformMagicTap}
```

It prints ALL available accessibility related things when set / implemented. Like you can see, strangely the UILabel of the table view cells implement the scroll method. This doesnt make sense to me. Why is this? Why not the UIPickerTableView itself? and also there is no trait saying adjustable in the entire UIDatePicker.

This is code I use to dump this information. I call it initially on UIDatePicker after 2 second delay just to be sure. I put this code in category on UIView.

```
- (NSString *)description {
    NSString *className = NSStringFromClass([self class]);

    NSMutableString *str = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@: ", className];

    if (self.isAccessibilityElement) {
        if (self.accessibilityLabel) {
            [str appendFormat:@"{label = %@} ", self.accessibilityLabel];
        }

        UIAccessibilityTraits traits = self.accessibilityTraits;
        [str appendString:@"{traits = "];
        if (traits & UIAccessibilityTraitAdjustable) {
            [str appendString:@"adjustable "];
        }
        if (traits & UIAccessibilityTraitAllowsDirectInteraction) {
            [str appendString:@"interaction "];
        }
        if (traits & UIAccessibilityTraitButton) {
            [str appendString:@"button "];
        }
        if (traits & UIAccessibilityTraitCausesPageTurn) {
            [str appendString:@"pageTurn "];
        }
        if (traits & UIAccessibilityTraitHeader) {
            [str appendString:@"header "];
        }
        if (traits & UIAccessibilityTraitImage) {
            [str appendString:@"image "];
        }
        if (traits & UIAccessibilityTraitKeyboardKey) {
            [str appendString:@"kbKey "];
        }
        if (traits & UIAccessibilityTraitLink) {
            [str appendString:@"link "];
        }
        if (traits & UIAccessibilityTraitNone) {
            [str appendString:@"none "];
        }
        if (traits & UIAccessibilityTraitNotEnabled) {
            [str appendString:@"notEnabled "];
        }
        if (traits & UIAccessibilityTraitPlaysSound) {
            [str appendString:@"sound "];
        }
        if (traits & UIAccessibilityTraitSearchField) {
            [str appendString:@"search "];
        }
        if (traits & UIAccessibilityTraitSelected) {
            [str appendString:@"selected "];
        }
        if (traits & UIAccessibilityTraitStaticText) {
            [str appendString:@"staticText "];
        }
        if (traits & UIAccessibilityTraitSummaryElement) {
            [str appendString:@"summaryElement "];
        }
        if (traits & UIAccessibilityTraitUpdatesFrequently) {
            [str appendString:@"updatesFreq "];
        }
        [str appendString:@"} "];


        if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(accessibilityIncrement)]) {
            [str appendString:@"{accessibilityIncrement} "];
        }
        if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(accessibilityDecrement)]) {
            [str appendString:@"{accessibilityDecrement} "];
        }
        if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(accessibilityScroll:)]) {
            [str appendString:@"{accessibilityScroll:} "];
        }
        if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(accessibilityPerformEscape)]) {
            [str appendString:@"{accessibilityPerformEscape} "];
        }
        if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(accessibilityPerformMagicTap)]) {
            [str appendString:@"{accessibilityPerformMagicTap} "];
        }
    }


    return str;
}
```

Comment: When the users swipes with three fingers?

Comment: No chance. Three fingers scroll up down on table view brings same result. VoiceOver reacts with 1 - 5 seconds delay, highlights next row or previous row in random way and reads label. Even though the table view cells are set to not be accessible. Also tried grouping property on the table view and/or on the parent view, with no luck.

Comment: What is the selected accessibility element and where is the scroll method implemented?

Comment: scroll method is implemented in the UITableView subclass. One subclass for each column in the date picker. There are 3 columns. self.accessibilityTraits |= UIAccessibilityTraitAdjustable is set in each table view. UITableViewCell subclass is set not accessible. But also tried implement action methods in UITableViewCell instead but no luck. Can't find examples on the internet on making such custom control accessible.

Comment: Why are you using accessibilityScroll instead of increment and decrement?

Comment: I have increment and decrement also implemented in table view subclass of each column but also tried in each UITableView subclass. it never gets called.

Comment: Please see updated question with dump of UIDatePicker introspection.

Comment: I do see `-[UITableView accessibilityScroll:]` being called on three-finger swipe. However, that doesn't help much I guess. I can't find a way to control the automatic VO scrolling. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/39603917/235297