# How can I make a UITableView with big header VoiceOver compatible?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uikit, accessibility, voiceover

My app has a table view with a large, blank tableHeaderView allowing to scroll the visible cells completely out of the window (to the bottom).
So a contentOffset of {0,0} means, the content is scrolled out of the window. The initial contentOffset is {0,{height of tableView}}.

This all works fine but I'm having a hard problem to enable accessibility for it.

The user steps through the elements, starting with the navigation bar and its bar buttons. As soon as she swipes again to activate the first cell of the table view, the table view automatically scrolls to {0,0}. However, since the first cell isn't visible at this contentOffset, it fails to focus on it and keeps the focus on the last selected element.

Can I somehow prevent this or control the contentOffset in VO mode manually?

I created a [demo project](https://github.com/futuretap/TableScrollVODemo) showing my problem.

Comment: Did you manage a solution ? Similar problem, when an element after the table view is in focus, the cells in the table view gets dragged down. This happens only voice over is turned on

Answer (score 0):

If there is no accessible content in the empty header, consider setting the content offset programmatically upon load in the event that [`UIAccessibilityIsVoiceOverRunning()`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/1615187-uiaccessibilityisvoiceoverrunning). You will also want to monitor for `UIAccessibilityVoiceOverStatusChanged` and do the same.

Comment: I do set contentOffset on load. However, when VoiceOver "tabs" to the table view, the contentOffset is automatically changed by the system - in a wrong way. I'm not aware of any event or hook to detect a VO switch to a new element and likewise I can't easily differentiate a correct VO scroll event from an incorrect one.

Comment: Hypothetically, you could use the [`UIAccessibilityFocus`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/1657010-uiaccessibilityfocus) informal protocol to detect transitions.